# Retagging [retagging], or a [tag-cleanup] tag cleanup?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

We have two tags on meta about what to do with tags: [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) and [tag-cleanup](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup).

Is there any meaningful difference in meaning, or any useful difference in usage, between these two tags, or should they be retagged, cleaned up, synonymised, and merged? In the latter case, which one do we want to keep and which one should be made a synonym of it?

<sub>Also, can I have a prize for "most meta question ever on meta SFF"?</sub>

Comment: Oh my word. We've actually gone full meta. Tag-ception has occurred.

Comment: Tagularity.....

Comment: It's metas all the way down...

Comment: People are far too busy worrying about site scope to think about meta tags... I'm staying out of the Scope Wars though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at this a couple hours ago...

I’d say [tag-cleanup](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup) should merged into [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging). I thought that [tag-cleanup](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup) would have to do with tag cleanup events, but that’s rarely how it’s used. If we want a tag for those events, it would be easier to create a new tag [tag-cleanup-event](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-event) and tag the [9 or so questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=tag+title%3Acleanup+is%3Aq+-%22harry+potter+tag+cleanup%22) that relate to tag cleanup events.

[retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) sounds less all-encompassing than a tag cleanup event, and [tag-cleanup](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup) sounds like either a general cleanup (i.e. retagging) or a cleanup event, so it’s ambiguous. I would suggest not even creating a synonym for it because of this ambiguity, if we create a [tag-cleanup-event](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-event) tag.

Comment: Done. And now that my question is no longer tagged with both [meta-tag:retagging] and [meta-tag:tag-cleanup], I can add the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag to it! (Oh, how meta.) Want to write a tag wiki for [tag:retagging]?

Comment: Sure, I'll write a tag wiki sometime. Do we care about [meta-tag:tag-cleanup-event]? Retagging 9 questions on meta without being disruptive would take months...

Comment: *shrug* Probably not worth it, since it looks unlikely that we'll have another tag cleanup event in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Ah, then we'll tag with [meta-tag:tag-cleanup-event] during the next meta tag cleanup event in 1000 years. That previous post must have given you a magical auto-ping. @Randal'Thor

Comment: Well, either that or I'm omniscient and omnipresent, and knew that someone had just left a comment ;-)